# Not able to access admin console of keycloak

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, istio-sidecar

Problem - Not able to access admin console of keycloak

Environment:

1. Kubernetes with istio proxy (Basically Reverse Proxy Environment)
2. keycloak running on http and ssl is terminated at istio gateway

Please help us to solve this issue.

Comment: What have you tried, got an Ingress? where is the cluster? how did you install keycloak?